# Sum of Adjacent column-row entries in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

This seems like it would be a common question but I can't seem to find the proper way to express it as I can't find an answer.

Say after row 4, I want E#n = C#n + D#n.  That is, for the nth row in column E, the value should be the sum of the nth row in column C plus the nth row in column D.  How do I do this?  Do I really have to write a separate formula for every line?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you're looking for is the default behavior for spreadsheet programs like excel and google sheets.  In row 5, column E just type =C5+D5 press enter to accept the formula, then hover your mouse over the lower right corner of the cell to get the '+' cursor, then double click of drag to fill down.

Example [file here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/198-4tvSCrnltXNV01OTTtwaZHYqJ7ApEjbHKEmeHxKY/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

If you enter this into the column you want you sum to start in, this will automatically expand to all the rows that have values in them

```
=ArrayFormula(if(C4:C>1,C4:C+D4:D,""))
```

Comment: Why do you omit values that are 1 or less, by imposing C4:C>1? I see no such restriction in the question. Also, instead of `if(condition,formula,"")` it is better to use `if(condition,formula,)` which will actually leave the cell _blank_. The first version puts the empty string in the cell, which is subtly different from being blank and sometimes results in unexpected behavior.